# Is there a way to remove specific emoji from being rendered in any application while using Cinnamon desktop?

Tags: cinnamon, unicode, emoji

I am slightly annoyed with some emojis.
So I was wondering, how could I remove/prevent some emojis from being rendered at all?
Replacing them with some other emoji like cute cat face could work too.

So let's say, I am annoyed by "", how can I make it show up as ""? Would be even better if I could make it disappear completely.

Comment: maybe you can modify the font on your system that contains emojis.

Comment: @stark, that's a good idea actually, I'll try looking into font modifications!

Comment: well, it took me quite a lot of time, but I don't have much experience with fonts, so it didn't really work out for me